# How to force DataSource termination and reload connection pool?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat-dbcp

Is it possible to force termination of a `tomcat-dbcp` connection pool and any open connections? And then reinitialize the pool, reusing the pool configuration?

```
@Autowired
private org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds;

ds.close(true);
//ds.open(); does not exists. how to reinitialize, without having to reconfigure the pool
```

Answer (score 1):

According the source code of [tomcat8-dbcp](https://github.com/apache/tomcat80/blob/trunk/modules/jdbc-pool/src/main/java/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool). After `close(true)` of `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy` is invoked, the class variable `pool` will reset to **null**. But a new object will be created using the same configuration once other methods access the `pool` variable. So you don't have to reinitialize the DataSource.